# Help solving a definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

I've been exploring a problem regarding dropping small circles on a large circle, and attempting to find the expected value for the covered area for a throw. The assumptions is that the smaller corcles midpoint is inside the bigger circle. But I met a hurdle when integraring a function that was suposed to find the angle to their intersection. So I'm trying to solve the following definite integral:
$$
\int_{R-r}^{R}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x^{2} + R^{2} - r^{2}}{2xR}\right){\rm d}x
$$

I know that: $0<r<R$. But I'm stuck after that. Wolfram doesn't seem to have any ideas either. Any suggestions to proceed forward $?$.

Comment: Maple gets an answer involving elliptic integrals:
$$ \mathrm{i} E\! \left(\frac{R}{R +r}, \frac{R +r}{R -r}\right) \left(R -r \right)-\mathrm{i} E\! \left(\frac{R -r}{R +r}, \frac{R +r}{R -r}\right) \left(R -r \right)-\frac{2 \,\mathrm{i} \left(R -r \right) r \boldsymbol{\mathit{K}}\! \left(\frac{R -r}{R +r}\right)}{R +r}+\frac{2 \,\mathrm{i} \left(R -r \right) r F\! \left(\frac{R}{R -r}, \frac{R -r}{R +r}\right)}{R +r}-R \arccos \! \left(\frac{2 R^{2}-r^{2}}{2 R^{2}}\right)+\frac{\pi  r}{2}
$$

Comment: Here $E(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind, $F(\cdot,\cdot)$ the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind, and $K(\cdot)$ the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.  Maple uses the Gradshteyn and Ryzhik notation, which is different from that used by Mathematica (which follows Abramowitz and Stegun).  See e.g. my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731607/ellipticf-problem-with-maple)

Comment: @RobertIsrael: cool! when I try in MAPLE the command 

`int(arcsin((R^2 - r^2 + x^2)/(2*xR)), x)`

I get a result that takes more space. How did you obtain your compact result?

Comment: If $\sin^{-1}$ is the arc sine function, you must use $\arcsin$ instead. The $\LaTeX$ code is $\verb*\arcsin*$

Comment: @DennisMarx You want 
> int(arcsin((R^2 - r^2 + x^2)/(2*x*R)), x = R-r .. R) assuming r>0, R>r;
and then clean it up a bit with something like
> map(simplify, collect(%,[EllipticE, EllipticF, EllipticK]));

Answer (score 1):

I asume that for you $\sin^{-1}(\cdot) = \arcsin(\cdot)$. As a starting point this could help

\begin{align}
&\int_{R-r}^{R}\arcsin\left(\frac{x^2+R^2-r^2}{2xR}\right)dx\\
&= \int_{R-r}^{R}\arcsin\left(\frac{x^2+\left(R-r\right)\left(R+r\right)}{2xR}\right)dx\\
&= \int_{R-r}^{R}\arcsin\left(\frac{x^2+\left(R-r\right)\left(R+r\right)}{2xR}\right)dx\\
&=\int_{R-r}^{R}\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2R} + \frac{\left(R-r\right)\left(R+r\right)}{2xR}\right)dx
&=\int_{R-r}^{R}\arcsin\left(\alpha\,x + \frac{\beta}{x}\right)dx
\end{align}

For the case $\alpha = \beta = 1$, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+arcsin%28x+%2B+1%2Fx%29) has a solution

For the case $a>0$ and $\beta = 0$, the solution of the integral is given in Gradshteyn's table of integrals (see photo below) [image]